# WSL terminal forgets to update and loses focus

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to use the WSL console in Windows 10 (version 1909) for some development work, but I find that often running processes will simply appear to have hung, but when I send a keystroke to the terminal it will update back to the bash terminal (as if had completed all along but hadn't updated).

I am running the latest version of the `debian` package from the store.

Is there anyway to make this problem go away or am I wasting my time trying to use the default terminal?

Comment: Guys, please don't vote to close - this question covers _software tools commonly used by programmers_ and is a _practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_. It is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Cheers.

Comment: I have what seems like the same problem, although I only see it when I run the X version of gvim.  The edit session comes is selected (is on top of the terminal window), but keystrokes are still being sent to the terminal. The workaround is the hit Alt-tab to select the edit window (although it was already on top!)

Comment: This should answer your question: https://serverfault.com/a/205898/551313

Comment: Dead googlers: I ended up solving this by moving to Windows Terminal. More of a workaround than a solution but since it's a far better terminal than the default I'm happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

Just a hunch, but I am guessing you are ending up in select mode. If you click anywhere in the terminal the title of the window will change to be prefixed with "select" and the terminal output will freeze so that you can select text without it changing while you try to highlight it. Pressing any key will cause you to exit select mode.

If this bothers you you can turn it off by right clicking on the title bar, clicking properties, and disabling quick-edit mode. Alternately, might I recommend the [new Windows terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), which handles selection and the clipboard in a more intuitive way.